# Difference between EasyMock.expect(...).times(...) versus using EasyMock.expect(...) several times?

Tags: java, unit-testing, easymock

What is the difference between this:

```
ResultSet set = EasyMock.createNiceMock(ResultSet.class);
EasyMock.expect(set.getInt("col1")).andReturn(1);
EasyMock.expect(set.wasNull()).andReturn(false);
EasyMock.expect(set.getInt("col2")).andReturn(2);
EasyMock.expect(set.wasNull()).andReturn(false);
EasyMock.replay(set);

assertEquals(1, set.getInt("col1"));
assertEquals(false, set.wasNull());
assertEquals(2, set.getInt("col2"));
assertEquals(false, set.wasNull());
```

And this:

```
ResultSet set = EasyMock.createNiceMock(ResultSet.class);
EasyMock.expect(set.getInt("col1")).andReturn(1);
EasyMock.expect(set.getInt("col2")).andReturn(2);
EasyMock.expect(set.wasNull()).andReturn(false).times(2);
EasyMock.replay(set);

assertEquals(1, set.getInt("col1"));
assertEquals(false, set.wasNull());
assertEquals(2, set.getInt("col2"));
assertEquals(false, set.wasNull());
```

?

Note: both sets of code compile and run successfully as jUnit tests. Also, note that the use of a "nice" mock is on purpose here.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To answer the question in your title - there's no difference.  Calling `x.expect(y).times(3)` is exactly the same as calling

```
x.expect(y);
x.expect(y);
x.expect(y);
```

(Note that as pointed out by Andy Thomas-Cramer, your specific examples aren't entirely equivalent because the order of calls differ.)

This might just seem like a convenience issue.  However there's a distinct difference beyond this: in that the `times()` case you can pass in the expected number of calls as a variable.  Consequently you can make this configurable by some external file, or even simply by a public constant int which you also use to fire off the test harness.  It's a lot more flexible than having to explicitly compile the correct number of calls to `expect()` (and update your code if you now need to test with five workers instead of three).

Answer (score 3):

The second is simpler to read and write. However, it would fail if the mock were changed to a strict mock, in which order of calls is validated.

Comment: So you're basically saying that there is no difference, really? I know if it was changed to strict it would matter.

Comment: No difference in terms of successful validation, for a nice mock -- but yes, a difference in terms of readability/writability. Consider times(42). And as @Andrzej points out, sometimes you might want the number of calls to be a variable.